# Using vue3-tel-input. Why v-model directive doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to use in my app on vuejs 3 this library [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/).
There is a ready component [vue3-tel-input](https://github.com/victorybiz/vue3-tel-input/).

Problem: directive v-model doesn't work - variable from data that passed as a model to component doesn't changed.

Every input event, which emitted from component, works three times - visible in the console.

[Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wozniak-qpww5)

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v-model` doesn't work in `vue3-tel-input` because that component hasn't [migrated its `v-model` implementation to Vue 3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html). The only migration that component seems to have completed is the plugin installation.

In Vue 2, the model property was named `"value"` and the model-update event was `"input"`. However in Vue 3, they've been renamed to `"modelValue"` and `"update:modelValue"`, respectively. Notice how `vue3-tel-input` [still uses `"value"`](https://github.com/victorybiz/vue3-tel-input/blob/be66175/src/components/vue-tel-input.vue#L93) and [`"input"`](https://github.com/victorybiz/vue3-tel-input/blob/be66175/src/components/vue-tel-input.vue#L478).

A workaround is for the consumer component to manually bind `value` and listen to `input` events, effectively implementing Vue 2 `v-model` in the parent:

```html
<template>
  <vue-tel-input :value="phone" @input="onInput"></vue-tel-input>
  <div>{{ phone }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueTelInput } from 'vue3-tel-input'
import 'vue3-tel-input/dist/vue3-tel-input.css'

export default {
  components: {
    VueTelInput
  },
  data() {
    return {
      phone: '+79991234567',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(phone, phoneObject, input) {
      if (phoneObject?.formatted) {
        this.phone = phoneObject.formatted
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/workaround-v-model-with-vue3-tel-input-urs44?file=/src/App.vue)